# Apache / Postfix / Cyrus - How do I restrict access to a certain domain?

Tags: apache-2.2, postfix, cyrus

Apache:
I have multiple domains on one hosting. I have a web-management software listening to port 3000 and one phpmyadmin. Can I restrict access to a certain domain?
I mean that example.com:3000 will work and notexample.com:3000 not? (same for phpmyadmin)

UPD: I have 3 IP's pointing to that host.

---

Postfix/Cyrus:
What is the right config to reject emails to mailboxes which do not even exist? (LDAP)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use allow/deny apache directives for any virtualhost you want to allow / deny access.